# R : how to call colnames inside r function

Tags: r, tidyr

Let me demonstrate:
(u is a df)

```
u %>% fill(colnames(u)[2],colnames(u)[3], .direction = "downup")
```

Would there be any alternative of doing so?
I would like to simplify code.

Thank you very much

Comment: This is a tidy-select/[NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) problem.  `across` would seem to be the obvious way to go.

Comment: What about `fill(2:3, .direction = "downup")`?

Comment: How would I do it if I would like to start from 2 to end of the df column? @harre

Comment: `fill(-1, .direction = "downup")`

Comment: Or `fill(2:last_col(), .direction = "downup")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill the second and third column, you can just use `fill(2, 3, .direction = "downup")`.

To reference the input to a pipe, you can use `.` as in `u %>% colnames(.)`. But this will not work here, since `fill` expects the column names as name, not as string.